# Magento 2 Full Page Cache not working

Tags: magento2, error, frontend, full-page-cache, fatal-error

Whenver I turn on FPC(Full Page Cache) feature in my Magento CE 2.0.2 site (doesn't matter if default theme or custom theme is running.) and when I open the Homepage of this site, then it gives "Internal Server Error 500" in the Firefox console, and the page is blank.

What could be the possible issue ?

Comment: Try enabling [developer mode](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#config-mode) to see what the error is (also look in your web server's error log).

Comment: Have you found a solution? we have the same problem on 2.0.6

Comment: Same problem for us on 2.1.1, PHP 5.6 FPM, Nginx. Enabling developer mode doesn't provide any additional information. The PHP error we're getting is ```PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdentities() on null in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 373``` The problem is in the function getIdentities() on the line:
```$identities = $this->getProduct()->getIdentities();```

```$this->getProduct()``` is null when Full Page Cache is enabled.

Answer (score 14):

We had the same issue after enabling FPC. The following error would occur:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getIdentities() on null in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Category/View.php:177
```

Not the most helpful error message but after some digging we found that this was being triggered by using the block type `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View` on our homepage - presumably because there is no category initialised at that point.

This was a coding error by one of our developers as this particular block did not need that type and was fine with just `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` which is the Magento 2 equivalent of `core/template`.

Answer (score 2):

---

> rewrite the function like this to handle the null values:

---

```
public function getIdentities()
    {
        $identities = [];

        if (is_array($this->getItems()) || is_object($this->getItems()))
        {
            foreach ($this->getItems() as $item)
            {
                $identities = array_merge($identities, $item->getIdentities());
            }
        }
        return $identities;

}
```